# Maximum Likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Let $x$ have an exponential density $p(x|\theta) = \theta e^{-\theta x} \text{ if }x \ge  0;\quad 0 \text{ otherwise.}$

a) Plot $p(x|\theta)$  *versus* $x$ for $\theta = 1$. Plot $p(x|\theta)$ *versus* $\theta$, $(0\le \theta \le 5)$ for $x = 2.$

How would I do this?

Comment: What plotting techniques do you know? Let's be specific: part (a) asks you to graph the function $1 e^{-1 x} = e^{-x}$ for $x \ge 0$. Where exactly are you having trouble doing that?