# exponential density & bernoulli distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, bernoulli-distribution

I had asked a question on [Maximum Likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53171/maximum-likelihood) earlier. Now I have two questions that are related to this question which had:

Let $x$ have an exponential density $p(x|\theta) = \theta e^{-\theta x} \text{ if }x \ge  0;\quad 0 \text{ otherwise.}$

Now suppose that n samples $x_1, ... , x_n$ are drawn independently according to $p(x|\theta)$ Show that the maximum-likelihood estimate for $\theta$ is given by

$$\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n} \,\,  \sum^n_{k = 1} x_k}$$

The second question is similar

Let $x$ be a $d$-dimensional binary (0 or 1) vector with a multivariate Bernoulli distribution

$$p(x|\theta) = \prod^d_{i=1} \theta_i^{x_i}(1-\theta _i)^{1-x_i}$$

where $ \theta = ( \theta_i, ..., \theta_d)^t $ is an unknown parameter vector, $\theta_i$ being the probability that $x_i = 1$.

Show that the maximum-likelihood estimate for $\theta$ is

$$ \hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{n}  \sum^n_{k = 1} x_k $$

how would I show that the maximum-likelihood estimate is given for either of them. I've been reading tutorials and stuff and I still don't quite understand it.

Comment: Hi Jonas, I have edited your mathematics a little. Please check that it still says what you want. If you want $\hat{\theta}$ instead of $\theta_h$, you get that by typing `$\hat{\theta}$`.

Comment: thanks I think there are a few changes that I need to make but it is mostly correct